# Drying out my flooded kitchen

Tags: water, flooring, water-damage, flooding

I came down this morning to see that a water pipe burst underneath my sink and there was an inch of water covering the whole of my kitchen floor. Oh no! I think it must have been spilling out water for at least a few hours before I came down in the morning.

After I turned off the water main the standing water drained into cracks in the tiled flooring after about 5-minutes, so there must now be a lot of water inside the flooring. I've opened all the doors and windows and turned on the central heating and put a fan heater down, and cleared out the remaining standing water.

I spoke to a local company for a quote for a professional drying service. They've told me they think I need a large industrial dehumidifier and an air mover for a week to dry everything out so I don't get damp, mould, rot etc. They quoted me £552 for this, and made clear that I pay for the electricity also! This was a lot more than I expected.

Any advice on whether this is a reasonable fee, how necessary this service is, whether I can do something myself (ie. if I keep the heating on and windows open for a couple of days and the fan heater is that likely to be enough?) etc. would be greatly appreciated.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
(I notice you were lucky enough to get a sneaky peak of my toes in the last photo, haha)

Comment: For that price, you can buy or rent a couple of fans and humidifiers.

Comment: What's under the floor?  Is it another room?

Comment: Yeah I thought that sounded extortionate. It's the ground floor

Comment: Is the floor built directly on a concrete slab?  Or is raised up and built on top of joists?  If it's the latter, then it's going to be difficult if not impossible to dry our the cavities between the floor joists, no matter who does the work, without removing at least part of the floor.

Comment: Either rent the equipment or hire the service company.  Either way you need to act quickly and get this dried out.

Comment: The only way to know if the price is reasonable is to call 2 or 3 other companies in your area. Obviously, you're somewhere in the UK (since you quoted a price in Pounds), but prices will vary around the world, and even around town based on local demand, so knowing if it's a good deal is _always_ off topic here. You should, however, make a decision fairly quickly, especially if there's wood below that tile.

Comment: On a different topic, if you can trace the source of the leak, odds are really good that we'd be able to help you plan out the fix, and that you'd be able to do that part yourself (assuming that's allowed under your local code).

Comment: If you have a wet vac, go along all the cabinet toe kicks to suck up the water that accumulated in there.  Your tile probably stops at the toe kick so water would build up under there. Maybe even drill a few holes in the cabinet floors to suck out the water with a smaller tube.

Comment: The leak is sorted that's not a problem. Most of the floor is concrete but one section is raised with a cavity underneath. That part was away from where most of the water was, so I think some water probably got in there but most drained out in the other direction from that space. I've got a dehumidifier in now and a fan heater, I've had advice to run them for around a week does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big fans and heaters (heat).   That's basically all you can do at this point.   If you act quickly the dehumidifier isn't really needed.   You can open up windows as it gets drier to do that.

The two issues I see is the water potentially holding (and not drying) underneath the cabinets and getting the carpet padding dry.

We do not know how your cabinets were made but if you could pop out the toe kick that would be ideal.   It does look like you do not have tile under your cabinets... And normally water would find its way out through the grout line, here it could be trapped.   So either you drill a couple of small relief holes at the very bottom - which still may not be the "real" bottom - or you just leave it and risk it.

A couple of hours of clean water is not a huge deal.   It's not like it sat there for days or was sewer backup.   I would just raise heat and buy/rent an industrial fan (or like 6-8 box fans).

The carpet... easiest way to get up water out of a pad is using a steam cleaner vacuum (hoover makes an $80 variety in the US).   These suck up water the best on carpet.   Note that you want to move this thing around because water will drain to probably one spot and it could be 10 feet away from your kitchen.   Drying out a pad is easy and relatively little chance of ruining the carpet and pad as long as it is dried in 1-2 days.   After you aren't getting any water in steam vac you just make sure a fan is pointed at the wet areas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've had quite a bit of heat going, and luckily today was dry too so that helped. The carpet I took outside and it mostly dried but it is still taking a while. The kick boards don't come out easily unfortunately so I'm just gonna hope for the best with with one.

Comment: It probably isn't worth taking the kickboards out.   You could drill a small hole through the bottom of the cabinet to gather a peak.   For "clean" water that you mitigate quickly though I don't see the point of taking them out.   Your risk of damage from taking out and trying to get back in is far greater than them staying there.   If they are MDF (which they don't look it), then they are already damaged.