# What's eating my chopping board?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I live in the UK. Recently my kitchen got very damp for a period after there was a leak in the roof, and I've noticed these little grubs eating a couple of my wooden items.

What are they, and how likely are they to spread around? Should I still expect trouble from them now that I have got the moisture levels in a room to be a bit more manageable?

[image: bug]
[image: chopping board being eaten by bug]

Comment: Biology mught be a better stack - we are not likely to be entomologists.

Comment: @SolarMike oh I see, I assumed it would be a common pest

Comment: This site might help.    https://www.londonhomecounties.co.uk/blog/woodworm-identification-11-types-of-2

Comment: You seem to get your kitchen wet often: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/224198/97780

Comment: @SolarMike haha glad to see you're keeping up with my kitchen, I also have another post where my main roof leaked if you're interested

Comment: That cutting board looks like it's seen better days... and those better days were some time last century ...

Comment: For some people they are protein, and they eat them

Comment: Are you sure they are eating the board, and not food deposits you haven't adequately cleaned off the board? I'd be inclined to simply replace the cutting board, or to resurface and refinish it

Comment: @crip659 ah I see it's woodworm, that's a word I've heard before but never actually seen one. I'll do some research on that thank you

Comment: @keshlam I left it in on the shelf in my kitchen a year ago with the intention of resurfacing it but didn't get round to it

Comment: @crip659 and Joe: putting those together looks like it should be the official Answer...?

Comment: @keshlam I would be happy to accept this as an answer if someone posts it

Comment: You can actually answer your own question... If nobody else does so, I'll post something.